# tmp directory path inside 'C' library

Tags: ios, c, macos, app-store, sandbox

My cocoa application uses one library written in 'C' which is tryings write file at '/tmp' path. This creates sandbox violations. In Cocoa we can use 'NSTemporaryDirectory' API. To fix sandbox violation Is it safe to use 'tmpfile' API in sandboxed environment? Are there in any other solutions?

Comment: Do you want a C API or does Obj-C API work for you as suggested in your question: `In Cocoa we can use 'NSTemporaryDirectory' API`?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I have removed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED After actually testing it**

No, `tmpnam()` won't work and I think the only way to get a temporary filename is to provide a `.m` file with your library specifically for use with iOS and OSX, which can be used return the temporary directory as a C-String:

apple.h:

```
#pragma once

extern size_t getTemporaryDirectory(char *buffer, size_t len);
```

apple.m:

```
size_t getTemporaryDirectory(char *buffer, size_t len)
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        NSString *tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
        if (tempDir != nil)
        {
            const char *utf = [tempDir UTF8String];
            strncpy(buffer, utf, len);
            return strlen(utf);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To me this is not working. I am getting following log in Console.`<AppName>(10920) deny file-write-create /private/var/tmp/tmp.0.7SUvca`. I am using following code to test in Sandboxed test application. `char *tmpFname = tmpnam(NULL);
    NSLog(@"Temp File name : %s",tmpFname);
    [@"Test" writeToFile:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:tmpFname] atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];`